# after which annotaion we can use @Override annotation?

Tags: selenium, annotations, testng

after which annotaion we can use Testng @Override annotation as i am trying to use it for retrying the failed test cases

Comment: `@Override` is not TestNG annotation, it tells you a method is overriding vase class\interface method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)